# Java 8 Stream Closes when using map inside map

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to join two streams together. I ran into the problem that my stream closes and I don't understand why. Couldn't anyone please explain to me why the following happens.

**The code below doesn't work. I get an exception on the flatMap function that the stream is already closed.**

```
private Stream<KeyValuePair<T, U>> joinStreams(Stream<T> first, Stream<U> second) {
        return 
                first
                    .map(x -> second
                                .map(y -> new KeyValuePair<T, U>(x, y))
                        )
                    .flatMap(x -> x);       
    }
```

When I first collect a list from the second stream and then grab a stream from that list it does work. See the example below.

```
private Stream<KeyValuePair<T, U>> joinStreams(Stream<T> first, Stream<U> second) {
    List<U> secondList = second.collect(Collectors.toList());
    return 
            first
                .map(x -> secondList.stream()
                            .map(y -> new KeyValuePair<T, U>(x, y))
                    )
                .flatMap(x -> x);       
}
```

I can't figure out why this happens. Could anyone please explain this?

**Edit:**

**Example of the code calling this function.**

```
List<Integer> numbers1 = Arrays.asList(1, 2);
List<Integer> numbers2 = Arrays.asList(3, 4);

List<KeyValuePair<Integer, Integer>> combined = joinStreams(numbers1.stream(), numbers2.stream())
                                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

// Expected result
// 1 3
// 1 4
// 2 3
// 2 4
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your code attempts to process the second `Stream` twice (once for each element of the first `Stream`). A `Stream` can only be processed once, just like an `Iterator` can only iterate over the elements of the underlying class once.

If your first `Stream` had only one element, the code would work, since the second `Stream` would only be processed once.

In the code that does work, you produce a new `Stream` (from `secondList`) for each element of the first `Stream`, so each `Stream` is processed once, regardless of how many elements are in the first `Stream`.

Comment: I understand why it doesn't work, thanks! Do you maby have some information on how I would solve this problem then? Seems like a waste of resources to have to produce a new List every time.

Comment: @Bob You can pass to your method 2 Lists (or Collections) instead of two Streams. Then your method will create one Stream for the first List and as many Streams as required for the second List, and return the joined Stream.

Comment: @Bob, alternatively you can accept not the `Stream<U>`, but `Supplier<Stream<U>>` parameter and use `supplier.get()`. This way you will not be limited to streams created from collections, code like `joinStreams(stream1, () -> IntStream.range(0,100).boxed())` will work as well. For collection source, you'll need to write like  `joinStreams(stream1, numbers2::stream)`